# Ingress SSL/TLS configuration with Cloudflare

Tags: nginx, ssl, kubernetes, cloudflare

I've created an ingress to serve my application, and configured it this way:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-api
  namespace: api
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - api.mydomain.com
      secretName: secret-tls
  rules:
    - host: api.mydomain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              serviceName: my-backend
              servicePort: http
```

Being `secret-tls` one secret generated using [this](https://nanjoran.com/2020/04/22/Kubernetes-Ingress-controller-with-Cloudflare/).

The problem is that I can use https if setting the SSL/TLS encryption mode to Flexible in Cloudflare (SSL/TLS -> Overview -> Flexible), but I get HTTP 525 when turning the SSL/TLS encryption mode to Full.

What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Flexible mode allows for http backends to be fronted by an SSL certificate. With Full SSL mode, the backend also needs to accept traffic on HTTPS (doesn't matter if it's a valid SSL or not as long as the service is listening on https - do you have that configured? E.g. should the service port be HTTPS instead?

Comment: Hi, @KedMardemootoo! I've configured the ingress this way: https://pastebin.com/MCDJvaxE, as I've saw in some tutorials, it appears to be sufficient. Do you have some observation?

Comment: I tried to change the ingress config to: https://pastebin.com/40aCYs6r, but I still having the same problem. In curl: https://pastebin.com/DfgJg9yn